# Windows does not display any icon ,only names display

Tags: windows-7, icons

Whenever I start Windows7 there are no icons displayed neither in desktop nor in any folder directory of  Windows.

Only names of the folders and files are displayed . Also no icons in the task bar either, it looks blank.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

note:

It did not work for me after running that .bat file these are the snapshots I think you can understand well. please take a look at that.

1.On startup: http://www.sendspace.com/file/ea823h

2.Folder directory: http://www.sendspace.com/file/pa68be

.after running .bat filehttp://www.sendspace.com/file/vgr6f1

and one thing is also happening on windows startup some SQL commands automatically run.see in link 1.

Comment: if the batch did not work, you are not facing an icon-cache problem. the answer lies elsewhere.

Comment: If you're the same user as S_PRATAP, please go to http://superuser.com/contact and have your accounts merged. Thanks

Comment: I was unable to comment so I did that...

Comment: have you seen the images in the link. if you have seen that snapshots then you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had this `.bat` script laying around **to fix icon-cache problems**, hope it helps you as much as it helped me in the past.

```
@echo off
set iconcache=%localappdata%\IconCache.db

echo The Explorer process must be killed to delete the Icon DB. 
echo.
echo Please SAVE ALL OPEN WORK before continuing.
echo.
pause
echo.
If exist "%iconcache%" goto delID
echo.
echo Icon DB has already been deleted. 
echo.
pause
exit /B

:delID
echo Attempting to delete Icon DB...
echo.
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F 
del "%iconcache%" /A
echo.
echo Icon DB has been successfully deleted. Please "restart your PC" now to rebuild your icon cache.
echo.
start explorer.exe
pause
exit /B
```

paste it into a text editor and save it to `filename.bat` . Run it with admin priveledges.

Comment: I have got the answer myself.  the problem is that I had changed the default icons of the Windows by registry long time ago but this problem is  occuring since  last two days. now I have deleted the key Shell Icons from the registry and every thing got correct.   
Thanks to all of  you for considering my question.